# How to use LINQ to select from 5 tables?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 5 tables:

```
course_id | course_name    (course)
------------------------------    
    1     | Basic1
    2     | Basic2
    3     | Basic3
    4     | Basic4
    5     | Basic5

course_id | trainer_id (course_trainer)
-----------------------------
    1     |    1
    1     |    2
    2     |    2
    3     |    2
    4     |    3
    4     |    2
    5     |    3


course_id | topic_id (course_topic)
-----------------------------
    1     |    1
    1     |    2
    2     |    2
    3     |    2
    4     |    3
    4     |    2
    5     |    3

trainer_id| trainer_name (trainer)
-----------------------------
    1     |    Tom
    2     |    Thomas
    3     |    Sue

tropic_id | topic_name (topic)
-----------------------------
    1     |    Skill 1
    2     |    Skill 2
    3     |    Skill 3
```

How can I use LINQ to select with result as below

```
Course_name    | Trainer_name     | Topic_name
----------------------------------------------
Basic 1        | Tom, Thomas      | Skill 1, Skill 2
Basic 2        | Thomas           | Skill 2
Basic 3        | Thomas           | Skill 2
Basic 4        | Sue, Thomas      | Skill 3, Skill 2
Basic 5        | Sue              | Skill 3
```

That is my code in C#, but the result isn't correct. Please help me, many thanks !

```
public class course_datatable
{
    public string course_name {get; set;}
    public string trainer_name {get; set;}
    public string topic_name {get; set;}
}

IQueryable<course_datatable> coursequery =
    from c in db.course
    join ct in db.course_trainer on c.course_id equals ct.course_id
    join t in db.trainers on ct.trainer_id equals t.trainer_id
    join ctopic in db.course_topic on c.course_id equals ctopic.course_id
    join topic in db.topic on ctopic.topic_id equals topic.topic_id
    select new course_datatable()
    {
        course_name = c.course_name,
        trainer = t.trainer_name,
        topic = topic.topic_name
    };
```

Comment: Your query looks correct. Are all the collections you're selecting from fully populated? What's the output you're getting?

Comment: What do you mean, “the result isn't correct”? What *is* the result? And what LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: @svick It seems the result isn't correct because it doesn't join the trainer and skill collections into a single row.

Comment: @pickles - The output is : Basic 1 --- Tom -- Skill 1 and Basic 1 ---- Tom --- Skill 2 and Basic 1 --- Thomas --- Skill 1 and Basic 1 ---- Thomas --- Skill 2

Comment: @svick : Yes, i corrected it. But the result like that : Basic 1 --- Tom -- Skill 1 and Basic 1 ---- Tom --- Skill 2 and Basic 1 --- Thomas --- Skill 1 and Basic 1 ---- Thomas --- Skill 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you seem unable to use my initial answer (which is preferred because doesn't require redundant join conditions), I'll work with your existing code and show you how to group and project.

Starting with this:

```
var coursequery =
    from c in db.course
    join ct in db.course_trainer on c.course_id equals ct.course_id
    join t in db.trainers on ct.trainer_id equals t.trainer_id
    join ctopic in db.course_topic on c.course_id equals ctopic.course_id
    join topic in db.topic on ctopic.topic_id equals topic.topic_id
    select new course_datatable()
    {
        course_name = c.course_name,
        trainer = t.trainer_name,
        topic = topic.topic_name
    };
```

You then want to `GroupBy` the `course_name`

```
var groups = coursequery.GroupBy(item => item.course_name);
```

and then each group needs to project into your new result type

```
var result = groups.Select(group =>
    new course_datatable
    {
        course_name = group.Key,
        trainer_name = String.Join(",", group.Select(i=> i.trainer_name).ToArray()),
        topic_name = String.Join(",", group.Select(i => i.topic_name).ToArray()),
    }).ToList();
```

or if you want to try something else (for fun) use LINQs `Aggregate` method, rarely used:

```
var result = groups.Select(group =>
    group.Aggregate((initial, next) =>
    {
        initial.topic_name += String.Format(", {0}", next.topic_name);
        initial.trainer_name += String.Format(", {0}", next.trainer_name);
        return initial;
    })).ToList();
```

Comment: Still error "coursequery does not contain a definition for GroupBy",  maybe i stupid, but Did you test it. I code in ASP.NET C# (Visual Studio 2010), database server is MS SQL sever 2008. Please help me

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Make sure your class has `using System.Linq;` at the top, if you're using .NET4

Comment: Yes i used "using Systiem.Linq" and .NET 4

Comment: Can i send my code and database to you via email. My email is hainlp@yahoo.com, if you agree, please send me notification email and then i send it to you.

Comment: I desire but i can't pay. Now i will try to resolve this problem follow your help.

Comment: i resolved with your help using groups. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @Hainlp You are welcome, I'm happy to have helped. Please mark the best answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Get your data from your database:

```
var result = context.Courses.Select(c => 
    new { Course = c, Trainers = c.Trainers, Skills = c.Skills }).ToList();
```

and then flatten the Trainers and Skills objects using `String.Join`:

```
result.Select(r => new 
{ 
    Course = r.Course.Course_Name, 
    Trainer = String.Join(",", r.Trainers.Select(t => t.TrainerName).ToArray()),
    Skill = String.Join(",", r.Skills.Select(S => S.SkillName).ToArray())
});
```

**edit**

Using your schema, I'll rename so that it should work.

```
var result = db.course.Select(c => new 
{ 
    Course = c, 
    Trainers = c.course_trainer.trainers, 
    Skills = c.course_topic.topic 
}).ToList();

result.Select(r => new 
{ 
    Course = r.Course.course_Name, 
    Trainer = String.Join(",", r.Trainers.Select(t => t.trainer_name).ToArray()),
    Skill = String.Join(",", r.Skills.Select(S => S.topic_name).ToArray())
});
```

You can do this all in one statement but I've structured it this way so that it's hopefully clearer for you.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Because it will try to incorporate the second `Select()` into the SQL. In other words, do the usual LINQ providers support `String.Join()`?

Comment: @svick you're absolutely correct - I've just added a `ToList()` that I had forgotten. Cheers!

Comment: var result = context.Courses.Select(c => 
    new { Course = c, Trainers = c.Trainers, Skills = c.Skills }).ToList();
Error : Course does not contain definition for "Trainers" and "Skills" Please review it. Thanks

Comment: @Hainlp You should be able to adjust the query to the exact naming of your properties. After all, you want to learn / earn / pass on your own merit.

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst - Thanks. I'm a beginer, i'm trying to do it. Can i contact to you via email? I need you help me more, my email hainlp@yahoo.com. Please

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst: can you see my code, when a course have two trainer, so the result have two records like that : Basic 1 | Tom | Skill 1 and Basic 1 | Thomas | Skill 2. But i want : Basic 1 | Tom, Thomas | Skill 1, Skill 2. Can you help me

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst : the same error, be cause Course table can not have trainer and skill field.